# HAproxy times out(504 error) with large POST bodies

Tags: ssl, https, haproxy, tls1.2

I have 3 nodejs web-servers spun on an ubuntu box and HAproxy to load-balance those servers on the same box. HAproxy listens at port 80(http) and 443(https, with SSL termination). There's no SSL between the HAproxy server and the web-servers.

The POST call to one of the api without SSL, passes through with any value of content-length, but when I try to do the POST call with a content-length greater than 8055 on the HAproxy with SSL connection(port443), HAproxy times out giving a 504 Gateway Timeout error.

Also, if I give an "Expect:100 continue" header to the curl command, the server responds with some delay, which I don't want to exist. Below is how the HAproxy config file looks like:

```
global
    stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 0777
    log  127.0.0.1  local0 info
    log  127.0.0.1  local1 info
    chroot   /usr/share/haproxy
    uid  nobody
    gid  nobody
    nbproc 1
    daemon  
    maxconn 50000

frontend localnodes:https
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/443_private_ssl_in.pem no-sslv3
    mode http
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend nodes
    timeout client 30000

frontend localnodes-http
    bind *:80
    mode http
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
    default_backend nodes
    timeout client 30000

backend nodes
    mode http
    balance roundrobin
    option forwardfor
    http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
    http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
    option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
    log global
    timeout connect 3000
    timeout server 30000
    option httplog
    option ssl-hello-chk

    option httpchk GET /

    http-check expect status 404
    server nodejsweb01 127.0.0.1:8000 check  
    server nodejsweb02 127.0.0.1:8001 check 
    server nodejsweb03 127.0.0.1:8002 check
```

I have ensured that the nodejs web-servers behind have no problem, they work fine. I have tried increasing the 'timeout server' period, no effect. 
Also tried a solution on [this link](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/724015-haproxy-not-talking-to-backend?page=1#entry-4167772) that tells to give an option ssl ca-file to the backend nodes, as follows:

```
server nodejsweb01 127.0.0.1:8000 ssl ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem check
server nodejsweb02 127.0.0.1:8001 ssl ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem check
server nodejsweb03 127.0.0.1:8002 ssl ca-file /etc/ssl/certs/ca.pem check
```

but after this option HAproxy throws an error saying no servers available at the backend.

**Please tell me what am I doing wrong in HAproxy conf file, so that I make the webservers respond successfully with the SSL connection**

Comment: Have you tried using bare-minimum HTTP-only configuration? e.g. `frontend/bind/mode http/default_backend`, `backend/mode http/httplog/httpchk/server`

Comment: yeah with a bare-minimum http-only config(no ssl), the server responds in time whatever content-length you give... its only while doing with an ssl connection, haproxy times-out

Comment: What version of HAProxy?

Comment: 1.5-dev21-6b07bf7, I guess its a 2014 release

Answer (score 0):

Try this minimum config:

```
frontend localnodes
    bind *:80 
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/443_private_ssl_in.pem
    mode http
    default_backend nodes

backend nodes
    mode http
    option forwardfor
    option httplog

    server nodejsweb01 127.0.0.1:8000 check  
    server nodejsweb02 127.0.0.1:8001 check 
    server nodejsweb03 127.0.0.1:8002 check
```

I suspect it's those additional options.

It could also be the SSL cert file. Is your PEM file created from a self-signed cert? How is it structured?

Comment: Yeah my PEM file is created from a self-signed certificate, is that a problem? Can you point me to a another way to create the SSL cert file?

Comment: Tried with the minimum config, but still the issue exists... I feel its the self-signed certificate like you pointed, which is causing the problem. Will check on that.

Comment: tried with a verified ssl certificate(not self-signed), it doesn't do any good.